# Inserting into an empty table is much faster than inserting into a populated table, why?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I'm loading some data from table2 into table1 on SQL Server 2014.  The tables have the same fields, though they are not in the same order.  I'm selecting each field and inserting them into the destination.

```
INSERT INTO table1(column1, column2, etc) SELECT(column1, column2, etc) FROM table2;
```

If I run this insert command on an empty table that is identical to table2, it moves the 3.2 million rows in a minute and a half.  When I run this on table1 (14Million rows of with existing data), it takes almost 3 hours for the same 3.2 million rows to be inserted.  So table1 should end up being 17.3 Million rows after the insert.  Order doesn't matter.

Why?

Is it because the fields are in a different order?  I deleted the indexes from table1, so that's not it. There are no keys or triggers defined.

Here is the estimated plan:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuCOv.png

Comment: Does the table have any indexes?  Does it have any triggers?

Comment: Please show us (all pertinent parts of) the CREATE TABLE statement for table1.

Comment: Also: you say you dropped the indexes, but did you check to see that in fact there are no indexes?  Because if you have foreign keys on other tables looking into columns of table1, then the RDBMS may have created additional indexes on table1 which you might not be aware of.

Comment: What is your clustered index? With that kind of difference in performance my guess is that you are clustering on a natural key (such as columnA and ColummB), so not only are you having to sort the new data that is being inserted, you are having the work out where to insert this in relation to the existing data. This is likely to cause page splits which will kill performance.

Comment: I verified that the indexes are gone from both tables.  Table1 contains 14Million rows, table2 contains 3.2million.  There are no keys defined on either table.  I just want to append the data.... no checks or sorting or anything, just add the new data to the end of the existing.  Seems so simple.

Comment: We really need the create table statement - Does your table really not have a clustered index (this will be your primary key by default)? There is no way it would take 3 hours longer to insert to a full heap table than it would to insert into an empty heap table.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProfitLossTemp](
 [FiscYrPr] [nvarchar](21) NULL,
 [Rate] [nvarchar](21) NULL,
 [AggLvl] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
 [Version] [nvarchar](9) NULL,
 [ValType] [nvarchar](9) NULL,
......
 [TotSGA] [float] NULL,
 [AmortAS] [float] NULL,
 [TIncExp] [float] NULL,
 [TOpInc] [float] NULL,
 [GiftCOS] [float] NULL,
 [NoteSGA] [float] NULL,
 [NoteAdv] [float] NULL,
 [FXAR] [float] NULL,
 [OIEFX] [float] NULL,
 [MiscAdv] [float] NULL,
 [MiscSel] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO`

Comment: I removed some of the columns since there are 50, but it's dead-simple.  That is the 3.2 million row table.  The 14million row table is the same deal, just different order of columns.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear, it is the definition of the 14m row table that I am interested in. Apologies for repeating the issue but I am 99% certain this is what the issue is. Are you **100%** sure there is no clustered index on `table1`

Comment: The indexes folder is empty for that table.  So unless there is one hidden behind the scenes somewhere, I can see no indexes on that table.  Also, the create statement for Table1 is identical, just a different order of fields.

Comment: No, there won't be anything hidden, unless you have an indexed view that references the table. Apologies for doubting you! I am well and truly baffled I am afraid. Last thing I can think of is can you post the estimated execution plans for each insert as an image?

Comment: @GarethD  Thanks a lot for the help.  I guess I'll keep playing around with adding indexes and see is I can make any gains anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I found this note which does not really apply to SQL Server 2014, but I thought I'd give it a try.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/297861

I created a clustered index on table1, tried my insert and it finished in 4 minutes.   I also tried it with a non-clustered index but I killed it after 30 minutes.

I'm not that well versed on why this is behaving like this, but it is.  I'm just glad to have the records inserting in a more acceptable time.  Thanks for the pointers everyone.

Comment: It appears that the default index created by MSSQL was a hash index rather than a clustered index.  I had no idea it would do that.  Well, it rarely happens that a legitimate question does not receive a good answer by the stackoverflow community.  Thanks for answering for the sake of future generations of programmers.  Don't forget to "accept" your answer when you have sufficient reputation to do so.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an empty table

The B-Tree for the indices are also empty. So SQL Server don't have to sort the tree.

When you have a table with 3.2 million records

The B-Tree for the indices are not empty, so SQL Server will have to sort the tree for each record that we insert. So it will take time.

Comment: I don't want it sorted, just appended.  Is there any way around that?

Comment: if there are indises SQL Server will automatically do it. One option is to disable NON CLUSTERED Index..  DONOTDisable CLUSTERED index it will leave the table in a corrupted state